# Http to https redirect not working for few pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

Following htaccess code is working only on home page. When I enter `my.example.com` in URL, htaccess redirects to `https://my.example.com` But when I enter `my.example.com/login`, it's not redirecting to `https://my.example.com/login`

(I don't want www in my domain name)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Options +FollowSymlinks

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1    [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


</IfModule>
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: `RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/` - you should not be using a [development install](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#development) in production.

Answer (score 0):

Keep redirect rule before internal rewrite ones and fix a syntax error in http->https error:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried it but Still the same